# Trying to target a parent elements child JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm working on a form and I've added in my own error messages that I only want to display when the user inputs incorrect text.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">First Name</label><span class="form-warning">(First Name can only contain letters)</span>
        <div>
            <span class="first-name">
                <input type="text" name="first-name" value="" size="40" maxlength="80" minlength="2">
            </span>
            <i class="fa fa-times hide"></i><i class="fa fa-check hide"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Last Name</label><span class="form-warning">(Last Name can only contain letters)</span>
        <div>
            <span class="last-name">
                <input type="text" name="last-name" value="" size="40" maxlength="80" minlength="2">
            </span>
            <i class="fa fa-times hide"></i><i class="fa fa-check hide"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both fields only allow for letters to be input. This is all checked with a `regex` on the client side. I've also got some server side validation but that's a seperate issue.

Anyways, the code which checks the input goes as follows:

```
function name(e) { //First and Last Name
        var n = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z -]+$/);
        return n.test(e);
    }
function invalid(input) {
        input.css({"background": "rgb(237, 209, 209)", "color": "red", "border": "1px solid red"});
        input.parents().find('.form-warning').removeClass('hide'); //Show Warning
        input.parent().nextAll(".fa-times").removeClass('hide');
        input.parent().nextAll(".fa-check").addClass('hide');
    }
    //Valid input show fa-check and highlight green
    function valid(input) {
        input.css({"background": "rgb(209, 237, 209)", "color": "green", "border": "1px solid green"});
        input.parents.find('.form-warning').addClass('hide'); //Hide Warning
        input.parent().nextAll(".fa-times").addClass('hide');
        input.parent().nextAll(".fa-check").removeClass('hide');
    }
function validate(input, type) {
        if (input.val() === "") {
            reset(input);
        }
        else {
            if (!type(input.val())) {
                invalid(input);
            } else {
                valid(input);
            }
        }
    }
//First Name
    $("input[name='first-name']").keyup(function () {
        validate($(this), name);
    });
    //Last Name
    $("input[name='last-name']").keyup(function () {
        validate($(this), name);
    });
```

the issue I am having is that this line:

```
    input.parents.find('.form-warning').addClass('hide'); //Hide Warning
```

and this line:

```
    input.parents().find('.form-warning').removeClass('hide'); //Show Warning
```

Is being applied on both fields when the first name is invalid/valid and the last name is invalid/valid. Ideally I'd like to be able to find the closest `form-warning` to the input in question and ONLY show/hide that.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just for the record, `.find()` on a class probably returns a list of jQuery objects for any matching class in that scope.  So if you call any other methods on the return of that `.find()`, it will get applied to all of them.

Comment: input.parents().find('.form-warning:eq(0)')

Comment: `input.closest('.col-md-6').find('.form-warning')`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't put `<input>` tags inside of `<span>` tags

Comment: That's the code generated by `contact form 7` for wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about:

`input.closest('.col-md-6').find('.form-warning:first').removeClass('hide');`

you seem to go too much upwards in your dom, so limit it via `.closest()`, which is basicly `.parents('<sel>:first')`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, this may help you

input.parent().find('.form-warning').removeClass('hide');

Comment: if (input.val() === "") {
   input.val("");
        }